# Possible to download Attachment body with CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I cannot find a CLI call to download the body (in binary) of an attachment.

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is no specific feature to download attachments with the salesforce cli.

You could probably use one of the subcommands under `sfdx force:data` to query/extract data from an attachment, but this really isn't the right tool for the job.

Something like the Salesforce-provided DataLoader ([relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm)) is better suited for this (and there's a CLI for it if you use Windows, if you're so inclined).

Comment: Already tried that sfdx force:data. The api returns a rest endpoint for the body of the attachment, and not the blob data. I can use curl to fetch the endpoint, but I need the user to login again as I cannot use the CLI login data to populate the curl with it. I ended up using a rust application instead of the CLI.